# notFound in getStaticProps Doesn't Short-Circuit Rendered Component

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I'm gravely misunderstanding something about the way returning `notFound` from `getStaticProps` is supposed to work.

This is in a vanilla Next.js (13) environment running in dev mode on a local machine.

I'm trying to implement what I thought would be simple 404 behavior from `getStaticProps`. (This is with the expectation that I'll be using `fallback: true` from `getStaticPaths`.) I'm returning `notFound: true` when there's no data matching the params, but I nevertheless get errors resulting from my page component (which shouldn't even be rendering) trying to access non-existent data on my props.

Here's the very stripped down example:

In the file `pages/test/[id].js`:

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const paths = [
        {
            params: {id: "first"}
        }
    ];

    return {
        paths,
        fallback: "blocking",
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const theData = params.id === "first" ? {
        name: "Brian"
    } : null;

    if (!theData) {
        return {
            notFound: true
        }
    }

    return {
        props: {
            theData,
        },
    };
}

export default function Test({ theData }) {
    return (
        <p>Hi there, {theData.name}.</p>
    );
}
```

Browsing to `/test/first` results in "Hi there, Brian." Browsing to `/test/blah`, instead of resulting in a 404, throws the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')" in regard to the `Hi there, {theData.name}` line.

This only happens when dynamic routing is in the mix.  Here's a very similar example from `pages/test2/first.js`:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
    const toggle = true;

    const theData = toggle ? {
        name: "Brian"
    } : null;

    if (!theData) {
        return {
            notFound: true
        }
    }

    return {
        props: {
            theData,
        },
    };
}

export default function TestTwo({ theData }) {
    return (
        <p>Hi there, {theData.name}.</p>
    );
}
```

In this case, browsing to `/test2/first` results in "Hi there, Brian." But if I change `toggle` to `false`, the result is a 404 as expected. (This despite the fact that my page component is identical.)

Comment: I just realized my stripped-down example should be using `fallback: "blocking"`.  Still doesn't do anything to resolve the behavior, though.